# Generate Javascript with custom tags in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates, django-custom-tags

my problem is a bit unusual.
In my project I have a static js file with many functions defined there.
Then in each template I have a script tag where I define the necessary variables for this templates and call the function i need from the static file. And the view does nothing but rendering the template. So my template looks for example like :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var first_var = 'foo';
    var second_var ='bar';
    my_function(first_var,second_var);
 })
</script>
<div class="values"></div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

And the view simply looks like :

```
def my_view(request):
return render(request, 'my_app/my_template.html')
```

What I have to do, is instead of having to manually write the script tag in the template, have a custom template tag to which you can pass the variables needed and that will return the corresponding script. The reason i have to do that is to allow people who will use the app to avoid writing script and only wirte something like :

```
 {% my_function 'foo' as first_var %}
```

I don't really know how to do this or if it's the right way to do so. The main point is using custom tags instead of wiritng the script, so how do you think this should be done ?

Comment: why do you think writing such tags is better/easier than writing scripts?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @prM I don't think it's easier, but I have to write the tags to make it easier for others, so they just have to enter the tag name and the parameters

Comment: bruno desthuilliers I know about the custom tags , it's what I want to write, but i don't know how to make a tag return a script, may be as a string ?